# How to avoid WSRegister* on a Free Pascal .dll/.so

Tags: lazarus, fpc, apache-modules

I finally had success compiling a "blank" Apache module, but now I've hit a rather annoying snag.

I want to communicate with a MongoDB server and I opted for the only lib around for FreePascal/Lazarus, [pebongo](http://code.google.com/p/pebongo).

Dependency for [pebongo](http://code.google.com/p/pebongo) is synapse.

Somehow I'm getting "/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_visius.so: undefined symbol: WSRegisterCustomImageList" when loading my module into Apache.

I've tracked down the symbols onto Menus.pp, I think, and lazarusall(something) also plays a role in this. Again, I think :)

How should I avoid those WSRegister* symbols showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some Googling about the WSRegister* symbols, I've found [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/lazarus@lazarus.freepascal.org/msg08779.html) a solution.

If you are doing a console program you should remove dependencies of LCL or add the Interfaces Unit into your main program.

I've done it by including Interfaces on the parent unit that I can edit, since placing it on the main program of a lib will not do it.