# Where or How, can I hook my code to the Unix signals(SIGHUP mainly) on a TDaemonApplication?

Tags: linux, signals, daemon, lazarus, fpc

After hitting the snag on the [Apache module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064026/how-to-avoid-wsregister-on-a-free-pascal-dll-so) I've turned to a Daemon Application([TCustomDaemonApplication](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Daemons_and_Services)) that is also needed for my project.

Once I realized that there were no obvious way to hook to *nix signals, and the one I'm looking is SIGHUP for config reload, I dived into the source. What I find out is that the whole concept is rather Windows centric and very poorly implemented *nix wise.

So, my question is, should I use a `daemonapp.(pp|inc)` of my own and include my own `fpSigaction()` calls under `Procedure SysInitDaemonApp;` or is there a "proper" way of doing it that I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If (all) apps are required to handle hup, then file a bug so that it is added. Otherwise just add your own.

In general I would try to use the daemonapp as much as possible. While a tad simplistic, it makes communicating about features a bit simpler, and one might get a few fixes and improvements for free in the future.

Comment: Thanks Marco. I;ll try and add some kind of, also simple, way to hook up into other *nix signals. Will report to the main site when done.